# C++: Format String Containing Hex Value

Tags: c++

Working with C++ on Visual Studio 2010.

Trying to come up with a robust function that will take a hex value as string and size as integer and then output the formatted hex value.

For e.g.,

If the input string is "A2" and size is 1, then the output is "0xA2"

If the input string is "800" and size is 2, then the output is "0x0800"

If the input string is "DEF" and size is 4, then the output is "0x00000DEF"

If the input string is "00775" and size is 4, then the output is "0x00000775"

If the input string is "FB600" and size is 3, then the output is "0x0FB600"

The basic idea is, multiply size by 2 and then if the string length is less than that, then add leading zeros to the hex value and then append it with "0x".

"0x" is appended irrespective of whether leading zeros are added.

As you see in 1st example, there's no zeros to add as the string already contains 2 characters.

I came up with below function, but it's having memory corruption. Also when i try to process large amount of data by calling this function few hundrend times, it crashes. Seems my logic has memory holes in it.

So am hoping that someone can come up with a robust intelligent code for this function.

**What i tried:**

```
void formatHexString(char* inputHex, int size, char* outputFormattedHex)
{
    int len = size * 2;
    int diff = len - strlen(inputHex);
    char * tempHex = new char [diff + 2]; //"2" is for holding "0x"
    tempHex[0] = '0';
    tempHex[1] = 'x';

    if (len > strlen(inputHex))
    {

        for (int i = 2; i < ((len - strlen(inputHex)) + 2); i++)
        {
            tempHex[i] = '0';

        }

    }

    strcat(tempHex, inputHex);
    sprintf(outputFormattedHex, "%s", tempHex);

    delete [] tempHex;

    cout <<outputFormattedHex <<endl;
}


int main 
{
    char bbb1[24];
    formatHexString("23", 1, bbb1);
    char bbb2[24];
    formatHexString("A3", 2, bbb2);
    char bbb3[24];
    formatHexString("0AA23", 4, bbb3);
    char bbb4[24];
    formatHexString("7723", 4, bbb4);
    char bbb5[24];
    formatHexString("AA023", 4, bbb5);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATED:**

I cannot modify the arguments to original function as this function is called from a different application. So i modified my original function with your code, but this is not working. Any ideas?

```
void formatHexString(char* inputHex, int size, char* outputFormattedHex)
{
    string input(inputHex);
    std::size_t const input_len(input.length());

    if (!size || (size * 2 < input_len))
        size = input_len / 2 + input_len % 2;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0x" << std::setw(2 * size) << std::setfill('0') << input;
    sprintf(outputFormattedHex, "%s", ss.str());
}
```

Comment: As you know, `strcat()` appends to an existing `\0`-terminated string. Please point out the specific line in your code which makes sure that the string that's being `strcat`-ed to is`\0`l-terminated. Additionally, it would be a good idea to work out with paper and pencil what happens when `size` is, say, 2, and `inputHex` is "deadbeef" (which is a valid hexadecimal number).

Comment: Why are you torturing yourself with C-style strings in C++? You can make your life 10 times easier by using `std::string`. Chances are that your problem will be fixed if you used `std::string` everywhere instead of C-style strings.

Comment: If you have numbers instead of strings, and if you're okay with C, `printf` or `sprintf` will do what you want.  Use the format specifier `%#0*x` and pass it your length and the number you want to print, like this: `printf("%#0*x\n", len+2, num)`.  (Or if `num` is a `long int`, use `%#0*lx`.)

Comment: Am ok with std::string. If someone can help!

Comment: @DonK "Working with C++ on Visual Studio 2010." you do have a calendar at hand, do you?

Comment: Not a bad compiler and it comes free with the Windows_SDK for win7, provides the Developer Command Prompt and installs in much less that 1G compared to VS Community which is a minimum 7G install to get the Developer Command Prompt `:)` (but you can forget about auto-ranged `for` loops and the other niceties from this century)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "from this century" thats my point ;)

Comment: Oh I know, I was just teasing a little bit. I throw in on the VMs I have just to avoid the full VS install. The C++ compiler (absent the lack of features) isn't nearly as much "fun" as the C89 aspect of it. That's when things can get really painful...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "was just teasing a little bit" Oh, ... you naughty playful thing! ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

std::string formatHexString(std::string const & input, std::size_t size = 0)
{
    std::size_t const input_len(input.length());

    // always round up to an even count of digits if no size is specified
    // or size would cause the output to be truncated
    if (!size || (size * 2 < input_len))
        size = input_len / 2 + input_len % 2;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0x" << std::setw(2 * size) << std::setfill('0') << input;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << formatHexString(   "23") << '\n'
              << formatHexString(   "A3", 2) << '\n'
              << formatHexString( "AA23", 4) << '\n'
              << formatHexString( "7723", 4) << '\n'
              << formatHexString("AA023", 4) << '\n';
}
```

### Solution without `std::stringstream`:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

std::string formatHexString(std::string const & input, std::size_t size = 0)
{
    std::size_t const input_len(input.length());

    // always round up to an even count of digits if no size is specified
    // or size would cause the output to be truncated
    if (!size || (size * 2 < input_len))
        size = input_len / 2 + input_len % 2;

    std::string result("0x");

    for (std::size_t i = 0, leading_zeros = size * 2 - input_len; i < leading_zeros; ++i)
        result += '0';

    result += input;
    return result;
}
```

### Updated:

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

void formatHexString(char const * inputHex, int size, char * outputFormattedHex)
{
    int const input_len(std::strlen(inputHex));

    if (!size || (size * 2 < input_len))
        size = input_len / 2 + input_len % 2;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0x" << std::setw(2 * size) << std::setfill('0') << inputHex;
    std::strcpy(outputFormattedHex, ss.str().c_str());
}

int main()
{
    char output[24];
    formatHexString("23", 1, output);
    std::cout << output << '\n';

    formatHexString("A3", 2, output);
    std::cout << output << '\n';

    formatHexString("0AA23", 4, output);
    std::cout << output << '\n';

    formatHexString("7723", 4, output);
    std::cout << output << '\n';

    formatHexString("AA023", 4, output);
    std::cout << output << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Am getting following errors for this code.

error C2734: 'input_len' : const object must be initialized if not extern 

error C2601: 'input_len' : local function definitions are illegal

And many more too..

Comment: @Don K I edited my answer to avoid everything I expect VS2010 not to swallow. If there are still error please be more specific instead of "many more too."

Comment: That code works! Now the problem is, i cannot change arguments to my original function as this function is called from a different application. Please see UPDATED section of my original question.

Comment: @DonK I've updated the answer to accommodate your updated question.